# problem understanding how to solve simple probability

Tags: probability

I am having hard time understanding how to get this probability.

Roll a die $n$ times. How many die rolls do we expect to show a value that is at
least the value of the previous roll?
For $j \in \{2, . . . , n\}$, indicator r.v. $I_j= 1$ if the value of the $j$th roll is at
least the value of the previous roll, otherwise $I_j = 0$.

$Pr(I_j= 1) = 7/12$  ( how would you calculate this? any help would be great thanks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: consider all possible outcomes of $2$ rolls. How many outcomes have the second roll's value being at least the value of the first roll?

> There are $36$ total outcomes and of those outcomes, $6+5+4+3+2+1=21$ of them have the second roll's value being at least the first roll's value. $21/36=7/12$.

Comment: ah thanks, that was simple.